# How can I test whether an array element is defined or not (where element can be defined as 0)?

Tags: c++, arrays

DISCLAIMER: I'm very new to C++ so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question!

I'm trying to read in data to an 1000 element array (`double`) and then if there are less than 1000 data points to read in ignore the excess elements for the rest of my program.

I've defined a 1000 element array and read in the data and now want to carry out a function on each element which has been defined by the read in data point. How do I test if an element is defined yet? I would use a Boolean algebra test i.e. `if(array[i]) {\\function}` but the data points can be any natural number including zero, so I don't know if this would work. How would I solve this problem?

Comment: What type is your array?

Comment: You probably cannot, unless you defined a type for that. In contrast to Javascript, C++ does not have any `undefined` value; however be very scared of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which happens often in C++

Comment: Yet you can just keep track of how many successful elements were read using an `int num` sort of thing. You'll know an element is not valid if it's not in the range, `[0, num)` or `[0, num-1]`.

Comment: Just keep a count of how many items were put in the array, and stop iterating when you hit that count `for(int I=0; I<count; I++) {...}`

Comment: @RLW: that should go in your question, so please edit it!

Comment: is there any illegal value. That is, a value that you shouldn't expect to be read in your array?

Comment: Also since you're using C++, your life could be a lot easier using `std::vector<double>` and `push_back`. That'll keep track of the size for you of the elements you inserted, so you don't have to worry about this constant, `1000`, and of having invalid elements in your array.

Answer (score 2):

The most typical approach to the problem of "the number of things in my array is not fixed ahead of time" is to have a variable that keeps track of how many things are actually in the array. Then, you just loop over that many things.

Since you add the C++ tag, you can (and *should*) use the `vector` class to manage everything for you — and you even get the added benefit that it can grow beyond 1000 elements should you happen to have more than that.

(aside: if you insist on sticking with a 1000-long array, you really should make sure you do something appropriate should you actually get more than 1000 data points)

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize your array with a sentinel value like NAN (i.e., not a number):

```
double array[1000];
std::fill(std::begin(array), std::end(array), NAN);
```

Then fill sequentially your array:

```
array[0] = 1.2;
array[1] = 2.3;
array[2] = 3.4;
```

And then break the loop as soon as this value is met:

```
for(int i(0); i < 1000; ++i) {
  if(isnan(array[i])) break;
  function(array[i]);
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b7ed85b080c1fd5)